# Only append parameter to class when condition true

Tags: php

I was looking at this code and noticed it seemed a lot of code just to run 2 checks, and I remembered coding in C# and there was a way to shorten the code to just one check but add a (something ? something) in it, is there a way to do something like this in PHP?

```
if ($config->get('core:twig.caching.enabled')) {
    $this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => $config->get('core:template.cache_directory'),
    ));
}
else {
    $this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
}
```

Comment: [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)   `$this->twig = condition ? value1 : value2;`

Comment: but I'd consider your code more readable then with a ternary. I'd leave it that way you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
$cache = $config->get('core:twig.caching.enabled');
$arr = ($cache) ? array('cache' => $cache) : array();
$this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, $arr);
```

Because I'm not 100% sure what `$config->get('core:twig.caching.enabled');` do return the above solution will work as your original one.

But if the return value is only `true` or `false` and if its ok to hand over `array('cache' => true)` or `array('cache' => false)`  than you can reduce this furthermore:

```
$this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => $config->get('core:twig.caching.enabled')
));
```

Comment: You can't do this because the constructor doesn't allow null, it has to be type array.

Comment: Than this is wrong in your question: `$this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);`